# Why would I hit recursion limit with @property?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a property that keeps hitting the max recursion limit, when there shouldn't be any recursion. I have no _ *init* _ method and therefore I am not initializing these variables at all. I would prefer to not override init.

```
@property
def key(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'key'):
        self._key = self.s3_bucket.get_key(self.key_path)
    return self._key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasattr` tries to access the attribute `key`, e.g. calling the property. This leads to an infinite recursion.

You probably want to write `hasattr(self, '_key')`.

Comment: As a possible solution, I'd set `self._key = None` in the constructor, and change that line to `if self._key is None:`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do `if not hasattr(self, "_key")`. Otherwise `hasattr(self, "key")` will call the property, which will call the property, which will call the property, which will....